# Add binary variable with size n in Gurobi

Tags: python, gurobi

I am tring to implement a facility location optimization model in Gurobi (Python interface). I have some difficulties to translate the model. The mathmatical model is shown below:

[image]

where dloc,floc  are the (x,y) coordinates of the demand (customer) and facility (warehouse) locations. The dloc quantities are constants (i.e.50), opposed to floc which are decision variables: these are calculated by the solver. also, x,y  coordinates are float numbers between 0 and 100.

One of the key issue is I dont know how to add the facility variable, the number of which can be any between 0 and n.

my codes so far:

```
from gurobipy import *
import numpy as np
import math


def distance(a, b):
    dx = a[0] - b[0]
    dy = a[1] - b[1]
    return math.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2)

customer = np.random.uniform(0,100,[50,2])
print(customer)

m = Model()

n = m.addVar(lb=0.0, ub=GRB.INFINITY,vtype=GRB.INTEGER) #number of candidate facilities

facility={}
for j in range(n):
    facility[j] = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="facility%d" % j) #certainly this is not correct, as an error is reported as 'Var' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

floc = ?
```

So I have tried another way by manually set a fixed number of candidate facility as an interim workaround:

```
from gurobipy import *
import numpy as np
import math

customer = np.random.uniform(0,100,[50,2])
print(customer)

m = Model()

###Variable
dc={}
x={}
y={}
assign={}

for j in range(10):
    dc[j] = m.addVar(lb=0,ub=1,vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="DC%d" % j)
    x[j]= m.addVar(lb=0, ub=100, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="x%d")
    y[j] = m.addVar(lb=0, ub=100, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="y%d")
for i in range(len(customer)):

    for j in range(len(dc)):
        assign[(i,j)] = m.addVar(lb=0,ub=1,vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="Cu%d from DC%d" % (i,j))

###Constraint
for i in range(len(customer)):
    for j in range(len(dc)):
        m.addConstr(((customer[i][0] - x[j])*(customer[i][0] - x[j]) +\
                              (customer[i][1] - y[j])*(customer[i][1] - y[j])) <= 40*40 + 100*100*(1-assign[(i,j)]))

for i in range(len(customer)):
    m.addConstr(quicksum(assign[(i,j)] for j in range(len(dc))) == 1)

for i in range(len(customer)):
    for j in range(len(dc)):
        m.addConstr(assign[(i, j)] <= dc[j])

n=0
for j in dc:
    n=n+dc[j]

m.setObjective(n,GRB.MINIMIZE)

m.optimize()

print('\nOptimal Solution is: %g' % m.objVal)
for v in m.getVars():
    print('%s %g' % (v.varName, v.x))
```

Anyone could demonstrate the translation of the model in Gurobi would be great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no problem in your definition for `n`. Nonetheless I rewrote your code to make it less verbose and easier to understand. First we create the given sets and constants:

```
from gurobipy import Model, GRB, quicksum
import numpy as np

m = Model()

demo_coords = np.random.uniform(0, 100, size=(50, 2)) # Just for demonstration

# Sets and Constants
demand = [f"i{k}" for k in range(1, 51)]
facilities = [ f"facility{k}" for k in range(1, 11) ]
dloc = {fac : demo_coords[i] for i, fac in enumerate(demand)}
maxdist = 40
M = 10e6
```

Note that `dloc` is a dictionary such that `dloc[i]` will give you the coordinates
for demand point i. Then `dloc[i][0]` is the x-coordinate and `dloc[i][1]` the
y-coordinate.

Now we can create the variables and store them in a [gurobi tubledict](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/refman/py_tupledict.html):

```
# Variables
floc = m.addVars(facilities, 2, name="floc")
isopen = m.addVars(facilities, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="isopen")
assign = m.addVars(demand, facilities, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="assign")
n = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name="n")
m.update()
```

Using [m.addConstrs()](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/refman/py_model_addconstrs.html#pythonmethod:Model.addConstrs), the constraints can be written as

```
# Constraints
m.addConstrs(((dloc[i][0] - floc[j, 0]) * (dloc[i][0] - floc[j, 0]) \
    + (dloc[i][1] - floc[j, 1])*(dloc[i][1] - floc[j, 1]) \
    <= maxdist**2 + M * (1 - assign[i, j]) \
    for i in demand for j in facilities), name="distance")

m.addConstrs((quicksum(assign[i, j] for j in facilities) == 1\
              for i in demand), name="assignDemand")

m.addConstrs((assign[i, j] <= isopen[j] for i in demand for j in facilities),\
name="closed")

m.addConstr(n == quicksum(isopen[j] for j in facilities), name="numFacilities")

# zip is needed to iterate over all pairs of consecutive facilites
m.addConstrs((isopen[j] >= isopen[jp1] \
    for j, jp1 in zip(facilities, facilities[1:])), name="order")
```

Note that while it isn't a problem to write `floc[j, 0]` in the constraint for the distance,  you can't write `dloc[i, 0]` since `dloc` is a python dictionary and `floc` is a tupledict.

Setting the objective function und calling `m.optimize()`

```
# Objective
m.setObjective(n, sense=GRB.MINIMIZE)

m.optimize()

if m.status == GRB.OPTIMAL:
    print(f"Optimal Solution is: {m.objVal}")
    print("--------------")
    for var in m.getVars():
        print(var.varName, var.X)
```

gives me the optimal solution n = 3.

Comment: In fact, I do not know how many facilities need to open. with a different data set there might need 10+ facilities open. Do we always have to manually define a (big) number for facility variable?

Comment: What do you mean by "facility variable"? The number of open facilities n? Independent from the data set, in this model `n` can't exceed the number of facilities because of the **numFacilites** constraint.

Comment: I mean the candidate facilities are countless as it is a continous facility location problem. Here I set facility variable "dc{}" as 10, which means there can only maximally 10 open facilities. But in real case, subject to the data, there might require more than 10 open facilities to obtain a solution.

Comment: According to your model, the candidate facilities are given as a set and thus aren't countless. Assuming the set of candidate facilities is countless: In the worst solution one facility need to open for each demand point. To meet your needs you could create the two sets such that the set of candidate facilities and the set of demand points are of the same size. Depending on the number of demand points, the model will be hard to solve in this case due to the number of binary variables.

Comment: If I set the candidate location variables the same size as the demand points, would it increase the computational time significantly? so what's your recommondation for such continuous facility location problem, especially when the required number of facility is hard to estimate?